# T-SQL script to get UDT data from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I need to select data with user-defined datatypes from Oracle to SQL Server using a linked server.

I created the same Oracle user-defined data type in SQL Server. However, it is resulting in "Invalid column datatype妼"

Query:

```
select *  
from OPENQUERY (Test_LinkedServer, 'select Test_UDTColumnName 
                                    from system.Test_TableName')
```

Will the above method valid direction/Is there any other scripts to get UDT data from Oracle to SQL Server?

Comment: What is the definition of the UDT in Oracle?  If it's a simple object type, for example, you can select the individual attributes as separate columns and then map that to whatever SQL Server columns/ UDTs you want.

Comment: It is simple user defined data type holding varchar value. I am selecting individual column/attribute(Test_UDTColumnName) in my query.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow.  Can you post the declaration of the UDT and the table in Oracle?  I would expect `Test_UDTColumnName` to be the name of the UDT column.  If that UDT is an object type, I would expect that you want `Test_UDTColumnName.A` to get the `A` value from the object in the UDT column.  But that's me trying to guess at what you actually have.

Comment: Type Definition in Oracle: create or replace type       Test_UDTColumnName force
                   as table of varchar2(128);

Comment: Test_TableName in Oracle is using above User defined data type to one of its column.I am trying to select this entity from oracle using linked server connection